# some routes giving not found err 404 node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

i am building an app on express js and till yesterday my apis were working now 2 routes show route does not exist when i use post man to get the data from db while others work fine

heres the working api
[post man get api working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyH4n.png)

heres the not working api
[not working api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BTzo.png)

heres the code in app js that is using the api

```
//  routers
const events=require('./routes/event')
const buses= require('./routes/bus')
const cars = require('./routes/car')
const hotels = require('./routes/hotel')
const auth = require('./routes/auth')

// middleware
const notFoundMiddleware = require('./middleware/not-found');
const errorHandlerMiddleware = require('./middleware/error-handler');

app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(
  rateLimiter({
    windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000,
    max: 60,
  })
);
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(xss());
app.use(mongoSanitize());

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.JWT_SECRET));

app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(fileUpload());

//app.use
app.use('/events/v1', events)
app.use('/buses/v1',buses)
app.use('hotels/v1',hotels)
app.use('cars/v1',cars)
```

heres the routes code

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { carPost,getCar,upCar,delCar,get1Car } = require('../controllers/car')

router.route('/car').post(carPost).get(getCar)
router.route('/car:id').put(upCar).delete(delCar).get(get1Car)

module.exports = router
```

only car and hotel api is not working which were previously working

Comment: `app.use('/hotels/v1',hotels)` maybe?

Comment: i am not sure what u mean

Comment: your are missing a leading slash, in the routes in question

Comment: ok i get it i missed the "/" thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are missing leading slash before hotels and cars routes. add '/' before routes

```
app.use('/hotels/v1',hotels)
app.use('/cars/v1',cars)
```

and i think before id as well you need to add '/' if you are dynamically querying something

```
router.route('/car/:id').put(upCar).delete(delCar).get(get1Car)
```

Hope it helps.